# How to add an class to all the li tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to give (via javascript) all the li tags on my html page an class. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: use the java script setAttribute() method to add the class attribute.

Comment: You can use jquery to do this. Unless for some reason you want to stick to pure javascript. http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
var length = elm.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  elm[i].className = elm[i].className + " classname";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pwf4z/

**Jquery**

```
  $("li").addClass("classname");
```

Comment: Please don't feed the [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

Comment: This answer is not just for the TS but also for people that have the same problem and can use the search function.

Comment: Perhaps `elm[i].className =  elm[i].className + " classname"` would be better, in case the `li`'s already have a class

Comment: You know, you don't even need the each.  `$('li').addClass('classname')` will work just fine.

Comment: True Andy, but then we also need an trim regex. `replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')` should do that trick.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx you are totally right, was still in the javascript state of mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var listNum = list.length
for(var i=0; i<listNum; i++){
list.setAttribute('class', 'className');
}
```